# How to discard rows over certain time lag from starting date by groups in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have the following data frame:

```
> df1

   ID  Timestamp            
1  A   2019-10-04
2  A   2019-10-06
3  A   2019-10-14
4  A   2019-10-22
5  A   2019-10-27
6  B   2019-12-02
7  B   2019-12-03
8  B   2019-12-31
```

My goal is to discard all rows per groups over a certain timespan (10 days) from the earliest timestamp in the group by `df1$ID` in R. So the expected output is:

```
   ID  Timestamp            
1  A   2019-10-04
2  A   2019-10-06
3  A   2019-10-14
6  B   2019-12-02
7  B   2019-12-03
```

So far I have only managed to compute time lags per groups but no idea how to go further.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to filter using `difftime()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = as.Date(Timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(difftime(Timestamp, first(Timestamp), units =  "days") <= 10)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    Timestamp 
  <fct> <date>    
1 A     2019-10-04
2 A     2019-10-06
3 A     2019-10-14
4 B     2019-12-02
5 B     2019-12-03
```

Comment: Way better than my dplyr solution (+1).

Answer (score 1):

in base R you can use `split` - `lapply` - `rbind` like this:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(x) x[which(x$Timestamp - min(x$Timestamp) < 11),]))
#>     ID  Timestamp
#> A.1  A 2019-10-04
#> A.2  A 2019-10-06
#> A.3  A 2019-10-14
#> B.6  B 2019-12-02
#> B.7  B 2019-12-03
```

Comment: Very nice answer(+1) but if I'm not wrong, the dates should be sorted in the groups decreasingly to make it work (in a general case).

Comment: Good point @s_t. It should be `min(x$Timestamp)` instead of `x$Timestamp[1]` in the general case. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

What about a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
# Timestamp as date
df1$Timestamp <- lubridate::ymd(df1$Timestamp)    

# here the job
df1 %>%
       # joining with a table that calculate the minimum date of each group 
       left_join(
                 df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(dmin = min(Timestamp)))%>%  
       # add the difference in days
       mutate(dday = Timestamp - dmin) %>%
       # filter <= 10 and remove the useless column
       filter(dday <=10)%>% select(-dday, -dmin)

Joining, by = "ID"
  ID  Timestamp
1  A 2019-10-04
2  A 2019-10-06
3  A 2019-10-14
4  B 2019-12-02
5  B 2019-12-03
```